Can a Student's t-test be used to identify whether or not a single observed data point should be judged as an outlier from a null distribution?
FYI: This question may be more thematically appropriate for Cross Validated's site, but, from previous experience, there is considerably less traffic there compared to Math, and I still feel that this is well-suited here, too.

I recently spoke with a colleague about methods for outlier detection among sample data. He asked if the following method was valid...and for me to attempt to explain its validity using what I knew about statistics:

Take your first 20 IID measurements. Deduce the sample mean $m$ and the sample standard deviation $s$. Let the 21st IID measurement be denoted as $x_{21}$. Compute the following "z score"  calculation: $z=\frac{x_{21}-m}{s}$. If $|z|$ is sufficiently large (relative to some significance threshold), then conclude that $x_{21}$ does not come from the same distribution as $x_1$ through $x_{20}$.

I pointed out what I thought were several issues related to a misunderstanding between the following concepts: Z test, standardization formula, and Student's t-test.

Firstly, in order to even make a statistical claim (i.e. output a p-value), we must assume normality of the dataset (otherwise, there is no way to connect our "z-score" to a p-value because the area under the curve of the PDF is no longer known, unlike the case where we have normality).  Next, assuming that all $x_i$ are instantiations of the same random variable $X$ (or, if you prefer the other formulation, of $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_{21}$ being IID), we clearly do not know what $\sigma(X)$ is. Therefore, we should immediately depart from the realm of $Z$-tests, which assumes that the population standard deviation $\sigma$ of $X$ is known.
Moving on to the Student's t-test (which also requires normality for the particular random variable under investigation)...consider the generic standardization formula of arbitrary random variable $Y$: $\frac{Y-E(Y)}{\sigma(Y)}$. Most commonly (at least in this context), $Y$ is the (random variable) sample mean of some experiment with $n$ sampling events, which I will denote as $\bar{X}^n$. Then the standardization formula of the random variable $\bar{X}^n$ reads as: $\frac{\bar{X}^n-E(\bar{X}^n)}{\sigma(\bar{X}^n)}$. It is well known that $\sigma(\bar{X}^n)=\sigma(X)/\sqrt{n}$, so we can rewrite our formula as:
$$\frac{\bar{X}^n-E(\bar{X}^n)}{\sigma(X)/\sqrt{n}} \quad (\dagger_1)$$
As stated earlier, we do not know $\sigma(X)$, which motivates the use of the Student t-test, where the t-test statistic is determined by the $(\dagger_1)$-similar formula:
$$t_{\text{test}}=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}} \quad (\dagger_2),$$ where $\bar{x}$ is one realization of $\bar{X}^n$, $\mu_0$ is the hypothesized (from the null hypothesis) $E(\bar{X}^n)$ value, and $s$ is one realization of $\sigma(X)$ .
In my colleague's situation, $n=1$, and, therefore, the resulting formula is:
$$t_{\text{test}}=\frac{x_i-\mu_0}{s} \quad (\dagger_3),$$ where $x_i$ should be viewed as one realization of $\bar{X}^1$ (which is really just $X$).
Finally, if we hypothesize that $\mu_0=m$ ($m$ was described at the beginning), then we have my colleague's desired formula (which is probably more appropriately described as a t-score).

MY QUESTION IS AS FOLLOWS:
I looked around quite a bit to see if anyone has mentioned this approach as a method of outlier identification. Now, I reside within the science community, where the formal treatment of statistics is scant, so I was not surprised to see that I had some difficulty finding sources that were in agreement...but I seriously found none, which made me wonder if the method was valid at all. The derivation I offered makes it seem like the approach is valid assuming $X$ is normally distributed (or, I suppose, assuming it has some distribution with an estimable solution for $\int_a^b f$...with $f$ being the PDF of $X$...). However, not being able to find any support of this method has me confused. Is this method invalid? Why or why not?

I know that this doesn't really answer your question, but I am reluctant to discard any outlier data unless I have some reason external to the data to think that that observation has been corrupted.  If I see a $3\sigma$ occurrence, I must ask myself which is more likely; this is a fluke,  my estimate for $\sigma$ is too small,  my data is not normally distributed,  or this data element has been corrupted.  All of those should be considered.

Scientist speaking: I think outlier definition is domain-specific. In my field, we can often detect causes/correlates of outliers, which greatly aids the definition, we care (almost) nothing for a statistical definition in the face of empirical data. While z-scoring is common paired with an arbitrary threshold, as are MAD-defined outliers, I don't know anyone in my field who takes a parametric null distribution seriously as an outlier definition.
